# Trying to mimic the exercise problem for solving PDEs in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

```
pde = D[y[x, t], {x, 4}] + D[y[x, t], {t, 2}] == 0
sol = DSolve[pde, y[x, t], {x, t}]
```

I am trying to solve the exercise problem in mathematica by slightly changing the differential equation, but unable to solve. I never  solved the pde using mathematica. I am trying to get colsed form soluction.

Comment: What's the corresponding initial and boundary condition? We already have several posts about dynamic Euler–Bernoulli beam equation, have you check [them](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=euler+beam+)?

Comment: Even also if I don't provide initial conditions and boundary conditions, I should still get a general solution right?

Comment: But I bet the exercise problem isn't about finding the general solution. Unlike ODE analysis, we seldom follow the "find the particular solution from the general solution" strategy when dealing with PDE.

Comment: Ok, but I am interested in knowing how the general solution can be obtained in mathematic, I checked some of the posts they are using  Laplace Transform. Is they any other way?

Comment: I'm not knowledgable enough to talk about general solution of this PDE, but as far as I can tell, almost all of the PDE solving techniques discussed in standard PDE text books (Laplace transform, method of separation of variables, green function method etc.) are about finding particular solutions of PDE.